# Merging screenshots and the generation of pdf file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to make a UITable with different cells containing UITextfield, UITextview and UIImage. I want to generate a report-like pdf containing all the cells including images and text.

I have the code for making one screenshots for UITableviewcell. But i dont know how to make multiple screenshot then merge them together to form a one pdf file.

Below is the code that i have for making the UITableviewcell screenshot. Thanks

```
NSUInteger index[] = {0, 0}; // section, row
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:index length:2];

    // Get the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Render a graphics context to turn your cell into a UIImage
    CGSize imageSize = cell.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [cell.layer renderInContext:imageContext];



    // Retrieve the screenshot image

    UIImage *imagefinal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();



       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagefinal, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: XCode merging ????? Edited.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya You're my hero.

Comment: @H2CO3: Learnt from you, and today i scolded 4 candidates for saying the same while taking interview :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - > are you project manager?

Comment: @Rajneesh071: No Technical Lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to take multiple screenshots but i hav done some coding for merging two images you need to make some changes to this code for merging multiple screenshots. Here is code.

```
        CGSize endImageSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

        endImageSize =  CGSizeMake(CELL_IMAGE_WIDTH,DesiredHeight);


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(endImageSize);

        // draw images into this context
        [anOriginalImage1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                               endImageSize.width, IMAGE1_HEIGHT)];
        [anOriginalImage2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, IMAGE1_HEIGHT,
                                            endImageSize.width, IMAGE2_HEIGHT)];

        //convert context into a UIImage
        UIImage *endImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        //cleanup   
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```